# jQuery use load() with param

Tags: jquery, forms, get

Exactly I want to do some trick in html.
I hope I can use jQuery to load a html in a block( like `<span></span>`).
And in the target html, I need the params in the url to do something.
For a.html is the main page, b.html is another page that be embed in block of a.html,
In a.html, there is a block like this:

```
<span id="rp"></span>
```

and in its' javascript, it do this thing( which I asked as the question of the title):

```
 var param="x="+1+"&y="+2;
 $("#rp").load("b.html?"+param);
```

It's all the main page do, and in b.html,

it pass the params in the url to do fill form of b.html.

In b.html, there is a form as:

```
<form id="myForm" action="192.168.1.xxx/goal.html" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="xs" name="x" />
    <input type="hidden" id="ys" name="y" />
    <input type="submit" value="test" />
</form>
```

(The goal.html is in another domain name, so I cannot use ajax in main page. That's the reason why I come up with this way to use method 'POST' to send data to goal.html)

and the javascript of b.html is:

```
window.onload=function(){
    function QueryStr(str) {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        var val="";
        for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            if (pair[0]==str) {
                val=pair[1];
            }
        } 
        return val;
    }
    //var test=setInterval(fillForm,100);
    fillForm();
    function fillForm(){
        if(isFilled()){
            document.getElementById("xs").value=QueryStr("x");
            document.getElementById("ys").value=QueryStr("y");
            //clearInterval(test);
            //document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    }
    function isFilled(){
        if(QueryStr("x")!=""&&QueryStr("y")!="") return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have tried use timer( `setInterval`) to be sure the data can be filled in the form after loaded, but the result isn't different.

The result of b.html should be fill the `input type=hidden` with params respectively,

when I use b.html with params in url, it goes all well, if I use a.html as the javascript(jQuery `load()`), the result of b.html will no params in url.

That is, if it operated correctly, the input field should be:

```
<input type="hidden" id="xs" name="x" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="ys" name="y" value="2">
```

but in the block of a.html, the field is

```
<input type="hidden" id="xs" name="x" >
<input type="hidden" id="ys" name="y" >
```

So, do I use wrong way of jQuery?

Any direction or advice appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (pattern)

```
  $(function() { 
        $("#rp")
        .load("b.html", function(data, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus === "success") {
            $(this).find("#xs")
            .prop("value", "1")
            .siblings("#ys")
            .prop("value", "2")
            };
        });
    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/aEQgD/